# Is it possible to relocate Cycas revoluta without harming it?

Tags: plant-health, transplanting

I have 2 Cycads and I plan to transplant them. Are there any special tips to follow to avoid harming them?
They are 10 years old and were planted 5 years ago.

Comment: Pictures please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are careful when handling the root system, and you plan the Cycas in a well-drained soil with these characteristics:

> The soil should be moist and well-drained. They are intolerant to overwatering or poor drainage. They are drought tolerant when established. Sandy, loamy soils with a pH acid to neutral are recommended.

you should be good.

More info on the plant and how to better take care of it on [this website](https://plants.ces.ncsu.edu/plants/cycas-revoluta/).